# Can't get file descriptor _write function to work - Windows 10

Tags: c, file-descriptor, stdio

Below are two versions of some simple code I wrote for Windows using VS2017.  They are selectable by the #if directive.  The first version uses file descriptor functions to open a file then write into it.  The second version does the same using stdio functions.  Both versions successfully open the file, creating it if necessary, but only the stdio version successfully writes.  The file descriptor version fails and results in a perror message of "C:/temp/fdio.txt: Bad file descriptor".  I've tried the file descriptor functions and flags both with and without the leading underbars but the results are the same.  Please tell me what I'm missing.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   const char *fileName = "C:/temp/fdio.txt";
   char buf[] = "This is a test";

#if 1
   int fd = _open(fileName, _O_CREAT | _O_TRUNC | _O_TEXT, _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE);
   if (fd == -1)
   {
      perror(fileName);
      exit(1);
   }

   int status = _write(fd, (void *)buf, (unsigned)sizeof(buf));
   if (status == -1)
   {
      perror(fileName);
      exit(1);
   }
#else
   FILE *fp = fopen(fileName, "w+");
   if (!fp)
   {
      perror(fileName);
      exit(1);
   }
   size_t status = fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp);
   if (status != sizeof(buf))
   {
      perror(fileName);
      exit(1);
   }
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

_O_RDWR must be OR'd into the second argument of _open.